# How to include scoped dependencies into dist with play framework?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt, sbt-native-packager

In a Play (scala) multi-module project I'd like to include scoped dependencies into the dist artifact depending on the scope I run the dist task in. E. g. having modules like this:

```
lazy val module1 = project in file("module1")
lazy val module2 = (project in file("module2")).dependsOn(module1 % "test->compile")
```

I'd like to be able to generate a dist artifact containing only module1.jar if I run

```
sbt dist
```

and a dist artifact containing both module1.jar and module2.jar if I run

```
sbt test:dist
```

The use case is that I'd like to be able to create a dist for load testing or end-to-end testing that contains certain mocks and I do not want to have that mocks in the actual dist that is build for production. The `test` scope here is an example, I'd like to use other potentially custom scopes, too.

I naively assumed that this would just work but unfortunately this is not the case. The scope of the task doesn't affect the dist task at all. I already did a lot of research with regard to sbt-native-packager but I wasn't able to define different `mappings` for different scopes. Is there any build-in way that I miss to achieve what I want? Or a different approach to support mentioned use case?